How to stop CogSci.SE from being listed as publication on Google Scholar, especially incorrectly
I noticed this a few days ago, and it has really been bothering me. For some random reason CogSci questions show up on my Google Scholar citation profile. Even more awkwardly, most of these questions are not even ones I asked/answered... they are ones I edited. An image:

Some of the questions linked (note that I am not the author of any of the questions, and only answered some of them):

Face-Blindness: Have I seen you before?
Is there a complete cortico-cortical connectivity map based on a useful partitioning of the cortex?
Does learning one discipline improve performance in another discipline?
Biological plausibility of bayesian models of cognition
Do people like those who are similar to them and why?
Is leg jiggling a focus aid?
Defining shyness towards strangers in confrontational situations
Are there sex differences in inter-rater consistency of attractiveness ratings  of opposite-sex faces?
Are IQ tests "biased" against individuals with Asperger's Syndrome?
Research suggesting conscious control over brain region activation? 

Google Scholar allows me to remove these particular "publications" from my profile, but I can't be expected to constantly monitor my Scholar Profile for every question I might edit on SE. As much as I love contributing to SE, I can't have questions I happened to edit in my publication record. Do I have to resort to switching to a pseudonym on SE, or is there something that can be done to avoid this?

Do the other SE sites show up like this? Just science ones? I'm not sure how Google Scholar picks this stuff up

@BenBrocka this seems to be a CogSci bug, my cstheory questions (some of which I am proud of) and my linguistics questions and answers do not show up. Further, all of the CogSci Qs that do show up are not even mine. I have edited in links to them.

You're not proud of CogSci.se answers :(?

@BenBrocka I didn't mean to imply that. I am very happy with some of the CogSci answers, but they are not publication quality. The biggest issue here, is simply that the questions being listed are not ones I've asked (and some I didn't answer) but ones I edited. I don't want my name to be associated as the author of a question just because I fixed typos or some format issues.

I think the follow Google Scholar query gets most of the offenders.

Also, here are 3 more from SO

The issue has been resolved, the 43 questions have disappeared and my profile is clear (without me having to manually remove the questions). I am not sure if the issue was on the Google or SE end, or if complaining here/twitter/G+ accomplished something. I feel like the olden days when power-cycling your computer magically fixed all your problems for no apparent reason.

I fixed it with my magic star on this question! Just kidding... wish it were true though!

See, complaining really DOES solve all your problems.
